# How to do linear search in a file?

Tags: python, linear-search

I am new to python and have trouble with my homework. I want to read a file from a location and look for how many times a number appears in that file. I have done where you read the file and get the list. I also used linear search in the program to look for the number. However, no matter what I do I will get the answer of the number is no in the list. Can anyone help me out here?
Here is my code:

```
import os.path
fLocation="C://TEMP//"
print("Assumed file location is at: ", fLocation)
fName = input("\nPlease enter a file name with its extension (ex. XXX.txt): ")

try:
    fin = open(fLocation + fName, 'r')

    aStr = fin.read()
    aList = aStr.split()


    def linearSearch(intList,target):
        found=False
        position=0
        while position<len(intList):
            if intList[position] == target:
                found=True
                break
            position=position+1

        return found



    mynum=int(input("What is the number you are looking for in the file?"))
    filenum= linearSearch(aList, mynum)
    if filenum:
        print("The number is in index: ",aList)
    else:
        print("The number is not in the list")
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug your Python code.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're converting the input into an int, but not converting the words in the file in the same way, The number `42` is not equal to the string `'42'`, so there's no way you can ever find a match this way.

Comment: Also, this code won't run. There are at least two errors, and I stopped trying to fix it after the second one. A [mcve] has to be runnable in order to be an actual example. You also need to include a small sample file to test against. Nobody can debug your problem. if you don't let them reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong answer because you're comparing `string` with an `int`

Your `intList` is a list of `string` and not `int`.You are parsing `mynum` to int while taking input. Remove the int parsing and your string will match.

```
mynum=input("What is the number you are looking for in the file?")
```

Also, if you are expecting `print("The number is in index: ",aList)` will print the indexes at which string is matched, then you'll not get correct output as it displaying the input list and not the list with indexes.